# How does the kubernetes cluster IP service pick end points?

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing

How does the kubernetes **cluster IP service** select pods to route requests to? Does it act like a **load balancer**?

This is what I observe. I have a cluster IP service with 2 end points. let's say pod A and B.
I sent 100 http requests in a loop to the cluster ip service. All of them are directed pod A while B is idle. After about a minute I repeat the test and now all the requests are sent to pod B while pod A is idle. So it does not seem to behave like a load balancer.

I have tried changing the time required for a pod to respond to the request. That did not affect this behaviour.

Comment: How did you configure your HTTP client and server with respect to connection reuse and keep-alive of the underlying TCP connection?

Comment: can you share your service YAML and the pod details as well?

Comment: you probably have session affinity based on the client's IP for your service. In this case all connections from a particular client will be sent to the same pod. Check spec.sessionAffinity of your service, it looks you have sessionAffinity = ClientIP.